# Best practice for ruby project and gemification

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm pretty new at Ruby. I have a Ruby project placed at Github. I created independently a ruby gem which I update manually on each release. To create it I just created only a gemspec file and It worked fine and I published it as ruby gem. My project doesn't have any gemfile. Is it recommended to add gem stuff to the project? Is a good practice?

In case of yes, I have a gemspec file which I could add to the repo. Could it be needed also a Gemfile, Gemlock file or anything else? because if yes, I don't have any of them, just the gemspec file. No idea about what could be the best option to "gemification"? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean when say "Is it recommended to add gem stuff to the project? Is a good practice?". Do you need to use a library (moved to a gem) in your project and you are asking about how to add to the project?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm asking if it worths to add the gem files to the project. For now my project just has markdown files and one .rb file. Nothing about gemspec file which I use to release the gem on each version. Should I add this gemspec file to the github repository?